# How to Access to path directly without passing by Root path in angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-router-guards

I have a confirmation path from backend

```
http://localhost:4200/newsletter/test@gmail.com/confirm?confirmationId=9c7f8645-9cb9-495f-a0df-f6a843944372
```

I need to access in this path from paste it in browser to confirm email

Link work if passing by home page

my routing module :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ConfirmComponent } from './components/confirm/confirm.component';
import { SignUpSuccessComponent } from './components/sign-up-success/sign-up-success.component';
import { UnsubscribeComponent } from './components/unsubscribe/unsubscribe.component';
import { UploadComponent } from './components/upload/upload.component';
import { UploadSuccessComponent } from './components/upload-success/upload-success.component';



const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ':email/confirm?:confirmationId', component: ConfirmComponent  },
  { path: 'signupSuccess', component: SignUpSuccessComponent },
  


  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class NewsLetterRoutingModule { }
```

path are not accessible and blank page appear in browser if click button confirmation received in my email inbox